# Can I fusion an external Hard Drive with the integrated hard drive on a macbook?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, storage

I'm a newbie here and i'm trying to save as much space on my hard disk as possible. I purchased an external hard drive and I was wondering if I can fusion it somehow with the internal disk on my MacBook. Is there any other way to use the external hard drive even better and save space on the internal hard drive?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! This may need some work and more details from you to yield good answers. What do you mean by "fusion"? Do you intend to *always* use the MacBook together with the external drive or will there be moments where you use the laptop without it? What kind of data do you intend to move to the external drive?

Comment: Hi, thank you!
There will be moments where I'll use my macbook without the external drive. I'd like it to download application from the Mac App Store directly into the external drive, for example.
I've read that there are some ways to combine multiple external hard drives and create an unique super hard drive and I was wondering if I can do that with the internal drive as well. Also, I'd like to get some tips and tricks about how to use the external drive as natively as possible. :D

Comment: The "unique super drive" will fail as soon as you use your MacBook without the external drive, so this isn't an option I would recommend to anyone.